# First x EACH row

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I use Firedbird and have a query:

```
select first 3 *
from tbkontrakte
join tbkurszeilen
 on fk_kontrakt = tbkontrakte.id_kontrakt
```

=> gives me 3 rows of result, fine.

Question: How can I say "give me 3 rows result for EACH" joined id_kontrakt?
=> should give me a bundle of 3 rows for each-id_kontrakt-of-the-joined-table

Answer (score 3):

Firebird 3.0 supports this using [`row_number()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-row-number).  If you have a unique id in the table, you can use:

```
select *
from tblkontrakte k join
     tbkurszeilen ku
     on ku.fk_kontrakt = k.id_kontrakt
where (select count(*)
       from tbkurszeilen ku2
       where ku2.fk_kontrakt = ku.fk_kontrakt and
             ku2.id <= ku.id
      ) <= 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There shall be a small error in it. Unfortunately I cannot solve it. The last but-one line "ku.id" is unknown. I tried serveral things to substitute it, no of my attempts was accepted. "rows" should be supported by my Firebird version.